# extract element value with XmlSlurper using groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I have a input xml like below where I want to extract 'Maker' value and pass it to an element:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                ../../Di/xsd/Doc/Data_0100.xsd">
    <Area>
        <CreationDateTime>2020-11-30T15:47:44Z</CreationDateTime>
        <No>
            <Id1>146520459</Id1>
        </No>
    </Area>
    <text>
        <Catalog>
            <Part>
                <Id>12345</Id>
                <Revision/>
                <Mixer>rtg</Mixer>
            </Part>
            <Dis>
                <Maker>7874</Maker>
            </Dis>
        </Catalog>
    </text>
</Data>
```

I tried like below, I need to fetch element2 and pass it as property but no luck:-

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;
def Message processData(Message message) {
     def body = message.getBody()
       
       def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body);
       
       def element2 = root.text.Catalog.Dis.Maker;
       message.setProperty("element2", element2.text());
       return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correction:**

```
 def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

The path is wrong.  Use `root.text.Catalog.Dis.Maker` instead.

#### edit

According to OP the actual error is:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types:
> (ByteArrayInputStream) values: [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@489dd356]

`parseText` is used for parsing a `String`.  `parse` can work with an
`InputStream`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, 
I tried but getting below error:-
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (ByteArrayInputStream) values: [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@489dd356]

Comment: Yeah it's `parse` and not `parseText`. Maybe if you would add the actual error you are getting to your question. Also tagging the question with whatever SAP environment you are running this would help.